# Make multiple hover for same element CSS3

Tags: css, colors, hover

Looking for a way to set a new color for every new hover over text/link with CSS3 only.
At the moment hover can have only last value.

```
.hover-text
    a:hover   {color:red;}
    a:hover   {color:white;}
    a:hover   {color:blue;}
    a:hover   {color:puple;}
```

Every new hover has to have different colour. Is that possible with CSS3 only?

Comment: No, you would have to use Javascript etc. You can't dynamically change the color for each iteration with only CSS.

Comment: this is not possible with the javascript but you can make use of javascript for this kind of requirement

Answer (score 1):

Yo can set css3 `nth-child` psuedo selector for multiple elements.

for single link multiple colors you have to use **javaScript** or **sass**

It might help

## CSS Hover Effect

```
 .hover-text > a:nth-child(1):hover {
        background:red;
    }
    
    .hover-text > a:nth-child(2):hover {
        background:white;
    }
    
    .hover-text > a:nth-child(3):hover {
        background:blue;
    }
    
    .hover-text > a:nth-child(4):hover {
        background:purple;
    }
```